Business Central: API settings to return localized column names in Power Query
I use Power Query to get content from Business Central. I fail to get localized (Danish) column names. Here are my findings:
In web ui: Danish column names, Danish content

When exporting to Excel: Danish column names, Danish content

When loading into Power Query without headers: No Danish.

When loading into Power Query with Headers=[#"Accept-Language"="da-DK"]: System column names, Danish content.

I have tried adding other headers with no success. How can it be done? I can add a renaming step i PQ but this would not be very productive...

i hope this can help you and give you some hints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/multiple-language-locale
BR GR

Thank you for your input. I have followed the link but find no additional info to solve the issue. Your link explains how Power BI (incl. DAX) handles language issues but my issue has to be solved in Business Central (BC).
I did try adding ?language=da-DK to the url, but BC does not respond differently.
But thanks for trying.
